# JAVA MySql multiple word search

Tags: java, mysql, search

i have a database in MySql that has a name column in it which contains several words(description). I am connected to database with java through eclipse. I have a search, that returns results if only name field contains one word. 
id:..................name:..............info:......................type:>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
1...................balloon..........big red balloon................big>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2....................house..........expensive beautiful............luxury>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
3................chicken wings.......deep fried wings...............tasty

these are just random words but as an example my search can only see ex. balloon and then show info,
but if i type chicken wings, it does nothing. so it possible somehow to search from columns with multiple words?
this is my search code below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class Search {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp``ut = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://example/mydb", "user", "password");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        System.out.print("enter search: ");
        String name = input.next();

            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM menu where name LIKE '" + name + "'";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Name: " +rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("Description:  " + rs.getString("info") );
            System.out.println("Price: " + rs.getString("Price"));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are performing the search now, you are at first vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and might want to use the PreparedStatement of JDBC instead of the normal statement.

Second, I would recommend splitting the user input at the space and searching for all the terms alone with "OR".

Example: User inputs `house expensive beautiful`

Search would be:

```
SELECT * FROM menu where name LIKE '%house%' OR name LIKE '%expensive%' OR name LIKE '%beaufitful%'
```

I have put percentage signs because if you would search for 'house', only the exact term "house" will be matched. By searching with "%house%", the strings "somethingbeforehouse" and "houseandsomethingafter" will be also found.

Hope this helps you!